# Plotting PMF jupyter notebook : ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, probability

Currently working on a task which requires me to plot a probability mass function to a graph. The mass function i have is to do with a biased coin being tossed three times :

```
P(H) = 0.75
P(T) = 0.25
X = 0,1,2,3
F(0) = P(X=0) = P(t,t,t) = 0.015625
F(1) = P(X=1) = P(h,t,t) + P(t,h,t) + P(t,t,h) = ‬0.140625
F(2) = P(X=2) = P(h,h,t) + P(h,t,h) + P(t,h,h) = 0.421875
F(3) = P(X=3) = P(h,h,h) = 0.421875
```

When i work to plot these points using the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prob = np.array([0,0.015625,0.140625,0.421875,0.421875])
x = np.arange(0,3)
plt.bar(x,prob, width = 0.5)
plt.xlim(0.5,3.5)
plt.show()
```

I am met with this error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of the `x` array must match the shape of the `prob` array. I can suggest the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prob = np.array([0.015625,0.140625,0.421875,0.421875])
x = np.arange(4)
plt.bar(x, prob, width = 0.5)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.xlim(-0.5,3.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Such an avoidable error staring me right in the face! Thanks for your help guys think i need to refresh my eyes lol

Comment: Just if i was to plot the graph of cumulative distribution frequency of CDF CDF = X < 0 = 0 
X<=1 = 0.15625
X<=2 = 0.578125
X<=3 = 1

Comment: How would i do so?

Comment: I would take a look at the numpy `cumsum` function, I think you can use it to build up what you need

Comment: Hi yes i have this code now just wondering how id plot a CDF graph and get expected values for x.

Comment: CDF = np.cumsum(prob)
print('CDF(X) = ',CDF)

Comment: Being your CDF a discrete function you can use plt.bars again. Or maybe plt.plot(X, CDF, drawstyle='steps')

Comment: Sorry mate ive literally only started with python hope im not irritating you but i am getting this error ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (4,) any idea why?

Comment: Got it sorted figured it out, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have 5 elements in `prob` and 3 elements in `x`. Python cannot plot charts if the number of elements in both arrays is different. Since you have 5 elements in prob, you need to have 5 ticks on the x-axis to draw the bar chart.

Change `x = np.arange(0, 3)` to `x = np.arange(0, 5)` and `plt.xlim(0.5,3.5)` to `plt.xlim(0.5,4.5)` and you should get the plot.

Comment: Thanks, cant believe i didnt notice that!